# For the two questions graph logarithmic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For the two questions
>   A) Graph $f(x)$
>   B) Graph $f^{-1}(x)$ on the same axes.
>   C) Find $f^{-1}(x)$.
>
> 1. $f(x)=\log_4(x-3)+2$
> 2. $f(x)= e^{x+3}+2$

For number one $x-3$ has an asymptote at $3$. I know that the line should follow closely to the asymptote. Can I use my calculator for this? I have a TI-84 Plus Silver Edition and was wondering if I can graph it like this: $\log(x-3)+2$ divided by $\log(4)$

Comment: By f-1x do you mean $f^{-1}(x)$? In (2) do you mean $e^{x+3}+2$?

Comment: Do you know how to covert f(x)= log 4 (x-3) +2 into a log of 10 so I can graph it?

Answer (score 2):

To convert it to another base, you'll need to use the [log law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base) $$\log_b a = \frac{\log_d a}{\log_d b}.$$

So, $$\log_4(x-3)+2 = \frac{\log_{10}(x-3)}{\log_{10} 4 }+2.$$

Comment: Okay, will do! Thank you so much!